# Unable to use https: ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: iptables, https

I have Ubuntu Server 20.04
Yesterday I'd spent some time trying to open port to my application from outside web.
So I was googling how to accomplish that task and made a lot manipulations with iptables (even not fully understanding what I am doing).
 Now It's ok, and I can access it from outside, but I can't access any resources by https.

```
curl https://mail.ru
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

What does it means and how can I fix it?
Thanks

Additional info:

```
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be one of possibilities :

- You have IP entry for that domain in your hosts file, but your DNS also resolve that domain in another IP

Comment: One of ? possibilities - did you mean to add another option?